# Why is this Action<T> call legal?

Tags: c#, discord, delegates

My friend raised an interesting question about this code snippet he drafted for a Discord bot:

```
public Action<DiscordMessage> OnMessageAdded = delegate { };

var embed = await channel.SendMessageAsync(embed: embedBuilder).ConfigureAwait(false);

OnMessageAdded(embed);
```

Our understanding of Action<> objects is minimal and we want to know why this works, for better or worse. We don't expect this code to be optimal or appropriate, but the more you know.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/delegate-operator `delegate {}` is equivalent syntax to `(_) => {}`.

Comment: So why can we slap a variable into the empty function? As attempted in the last line of code.

Comment: `Action<DiscordMessage>` takes an argument. From the above; "When you use the delegate operator, you might omit the parameter list. If you do that, the created anonymous method can be converted to a delegate type with any list of parameters". It's the assignment `OnMessageAdded = delegate ...` where the delegate is coerced to the correct type.

Comment: Aaah, I see. So because embed is a DiscordMessage, it can be passed into the empty delegate which has been converted into an Action<DiscordMessage>, correct? In this case it does nothing.

Comment: Right, `OnMessageAdded` contains a valid delegate, which does nothing.

Comment: Got it. Thank you for clearing that up!

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I would mention that no conversation happens at all here the delegate  creates a delegate with parameters  For a good representation of what happens you can look at https://sharplab.io/

Comment: By "coerced", I mean that the compiler will add the parameters to the IL implementation to match the method signature of the assignment.

Answer (score 2):

The empty delegate becomes of type `Action<DiscordMessage>` when `OnMessageAdded` is defined. This allows `OnMessageAdded` to take a `DiscordMessage` as an argument, but it will do nothing.